# Keeping things secret while using paramiko?

Tags: python, python-2.7, encryption, ssh, paramiko

I'm making an software which uploads files to my linux vps and then executes few commands there. As I can see, Paramiko is best option to do that, but only problem is keeping my vps login credentials safe. I don't want anyone who knows how to decompile py2exe or .pyc (which is not that hard nowadays) to get my root credentials. I looked into encrypt/decrypt but that actually doesn't solve my problem since I have to store string with real username/password inside code to be encrypted and later decrypted... To sum up, I want to know is there any way to keep my vps credentials safe and secure from users while using Paramiko?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a SSH key
2. Set your key's public part as an authorized key on the server
3. Make your software use said SSH key

With paramiko:

```
client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.connect('127.0.0.1', username='user', key_filename='/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa')
```